# Derive and Update Column Value based on Row Value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a Request History table that I would like to flag its versions (version is based on end of cycle); I was able to mark the end of the cycle, but somehow I couldn't update the values of each associated with each cycle. Here is an example:

```
    |history_id   | Req_id | StatID | Time      |EndCycleDate |
    |-------------|---------|-------|---------- |-------------|
    |1            | 1       |18     | 3/26/2017 |   NULL      |
    |2            | 1       | 19    | 3/26/2017 |   NULL      |
    |3            | 1       |20     | 3/30/2017 |   NULL      |
    |4            |1        | 23    |3/30/2017  |   NULL      |
    |5            | 1       |35     |3/30/2017  |   3/30/2017 |
    |6            | 1       |33     |4/4/2017   |   NULL      |
    |7            | 1       |34     |4/4/2017   |   NULL      |
    |8            | 1       |39     |4/4/2017   |   NULL      |
    |9            | 1       |35     |4/4/2017   |   4/4/2017  |
    |10           | 1       |33     |4/5/2017   |   NULL      |
    |11           | 1       |34     |4/6/2017   |   NULL      |
     |12          | 1       |39     |4/6/2017   |   NULL      |
    |13           | 1       |35     |4/7/2017   |   4/7/2017  |
    |14           | 1       |33     |4/8/2017   |   NULL      |
    |15           | 1       |  34   |4/8/2017   |   NULL      |
    |16           | 2       |18     |3/28/2017  |   NULL      |
    |17           | 2       |26     |3/28/2017  |   NULL      |
    |18           | 2       |20     |3/30/2017  |   NULL      |
    |19           | 2       |23     |3/30/2017  |   NULL      |
    |20           | 2       |35     |3/30/2017  |   3/30/2017 |
    |21           | 2       |33     |4/12/2017  |   NULL      |
    |22           | 2       |34     |4/12/2017  |   NULL      |
    |23           | 2       |38     |4/13/2017  |   NULL      |
```

Now what I would like to achieve is to derive a new column, namely VER, and update its value like the following:

```
    |history_id   | Req_id | StatID | Time      |EndCycleDate | VER  |
    |-------------|---------|-------|---------- |-------------|------|
    |1            | 1       |18     | 3/26/2017 |   NULL      |  1   |
    |2            | 1       | 19    | 3/26/2017 |   NULL      |  1   |
    |3            | 1       |20     | 3/30/2017 |   NULL      |  1   |
    |4            |1        | 23    |3/30/2017  |   NULL      |  1   |
    |5            | 1       |35     |3/30/2017  |   3/30/2017 |  1   |
    |6            | 1       |33     |4/4/2017   |   NULL      |  2   |
    |7            | 1       |34     |4/4/2017   |   NULL      |  2   |
    |8            | 1       |39     |4/4/2017   |   NULL      |  2   |
    |9            | 1       |35     |4/4/2017   |   4/4/2017  |  2   |
    |10           | 1       |33     |4/5/2017   |   NULL      |  3   |
    |11           | 1       |34     |4/6/2017   |   NULL      |  3   |
    |12           | 1       |39     |4/6/2017   |   NULL      |  3   |
    |13           | 1       |35     |4/7/2017   |   4/7/2017  |  3   |
    |14           | 1       |33     |4/8/2017   |   NULL      |  4   |
    |15           | 1       |  34   |4/8/2017   |   NULL      |  4   |
    |16           | 2       |18     |3/28/2017  |   NULL      |  1   |
    |17           | 2       |26     |3/28/2017  |   NULL      |  1   |
    |18           | 2       |20     |3/30/2017  |   NULL      |  1   |
    |19           | 2       |23     |3/30/2017  |   NULL      |  1   |
    |20           | 2       |35     |3/30/2017  |   3/30/2017 |  1   |
    |21           | 2       |33     |4/12/2017  |   NULL      |  2   |
    |22           | 2       |34     |4/12/2017  |   NULL      | 2    |
    |23           | 2       |38     |4/13/2017  |   NULL      | 2    |
```

Comment: If you remove the `----` lines, it will become much easier to read the question.

Comment: Done. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method that comes really close is a cumulative count:

```
select t.*,
       count(endCycleDate) over (partition by req_id order by history_id) as ver
from t;
```

However, this doesn't get the value when the endCycle date is defined exactly right.  And the value starts at 0.  Most of these problems are fixed with a windowing clause:

```
select t.*,
       (count(endCycleDate) over (partition by req_id 
                                  order by history_id
                                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) + 1
       ) as ver
from t;
```

But that misses the value on the first row first one.  So, here is a method that actually works.  It enumerates the values *backward* and then subtracts from the total to get the versions in ascending order:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + count(*) over (partition by req_id) -
        (count(endCycleDate) over (partition by req_id 
                                   order by history_id desc)
       ) as ver
from t;
```

Comment: i think `and 1 precending)` this should be 1 following

Comment: WOW! thanks for your quick response! I ran it however, is kind of different of what I had in mind. the instead of 1 Ver started with 16 all the way down to 8

Comment: @TheGameiswar . . . That won't work.  That only works for, say, history id 8 but not for the ones before that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks!!! you second solution is exactly what I was looking for! I will do a lot more testing, but really your help is really appreciated!!!.